# How can I insert a subview below the other subviews

Tags: ios, subview, addsubview

everyone.

I have some labels that I draw them in the xib file, and
add a background view using codes,but the background view 
is in the front of these labels, so I cant see them. So, 
my question is how can I add a background view below these
labels.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you Google `UIView` you'll end up at the documentation - [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Then you need to look down the list of methods until you find something that sounds like it will roughly fit your needs like these two:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

and

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view belowSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview
```

At this point you just have to read the descriptions of how the methods behave and pick whichever one is easiest to implement for your design. It's really good for your own learning if you try to find the answer yourself before you ask a question

Comment: Thank you! I will google first and find the answer. Your advice is helpful.

Comment: Once you get used to looking at the docs you'll find answers are a lot easier to come by - it's just hard to know where to start with them

Answer (score 44):

You can use the method [`insertSubview:atIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW19)

```
[self.view insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can call this method in Swift 3

```
view.insertSubview(yourSubView, at: 0)
```

or

```
view.sendSubview(toBack: yourSubView)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3 and later.**

```
view.insertSubview(theViewYouWantToAdd, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In IB the subviews of a view are listed in a hierarchy under that view. Subviews which appear above their siblings in that hierarchy will appear below them in the rendered view. So in the example below, the `in` `99:99 AM` label appears under the `Sign In` button at runtime.

If your background is just a UIImageView, consider adding the view to your NIB and then setting its UIImage at runtime. That way, you don't get confused. Also, [what Paul.s said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10051529/1224741).

[image]

Comment: The OP is talking about adding a view in code outside of the xib.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/swift-programming/dynamic-layouts-in-swift-b56cf8049b08

Use VerticalLayout as the parent. it is quite simple and effective