# iOS: add a subview to the second to highest position

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview, addsubview

How can I add a subview to the second to highest position on the stack? That is, say I have 3 subviews, with number 3 being the visible on top. How can I add a new view that is directly below that one and push the rest down?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051514/how-can-i-insert-a-subview-below-the-other-subviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you have 3 subviews on your parentView.
after adding all the subviews 
call this method-

```
[parentView insertSubview:yourView atIndex:parentView.subviews.count-1]
```

there are also other simpler methods  such as

```
[parentView insertSubview: aboveSubview: ]
[parentView insertSubview: belowSubview: ]
```

Cheers , hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

There is this API:

insertSubview:newView belowSubview:oldView

didn't see it when I first looked at the documentation :)

BUT, if we didn't have a reference to out previous view, does anyone know a way we could get the last subview?